# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - August 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 11th edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

This report introduces some minor changes to the terminology used to better convey what the metrics are showing. However, these changes in no way alter the results.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for August 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              500
2   Allan                     250
3   unknowndomain             240
4   bmike                     160
5   Tetsujin, Monomeeth       130
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,597 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-08-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              277
2   unknowndomain             112
3   bmike                      97
4   IconDaemon                 46
5   jaume                      38
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,412
2   Nimesh Neema              633
3   Monomeeth                 329
4   bmike                     268
5   unknowndomain             147
```

A big thank you to all 56 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Mark                       63
2   Nimesh Neema               62
3   Allan                      58
4   jaume                      51
5   fsb                        38
```

A big thank you to all 24 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              342
2   unknowndomain             142
3   Monomeeth                 111
4   jaume                     101
5   fsb                        63
```

A big thank you to all 34 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                  66
2   Nimesh Neema               63
3   Glorfindel                 36
4   Allan                      31
5   Tetsujin                   30
```

A big thank you to all 26 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      49
2   Nimesh Neema               45
3   Tetsujin                   38
4   unknowndomain              33
5   jaume                      30
```

A big thank you to all 29 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan, Mark                 7
2   Nimesh Neema, jaume         6
3   IconDaemon                  5
4   Tetsujin, fsb, bmike        3 
5   JBis, unknowndomain,
    nohillside, grg             2
```

A big thank you to all 14 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               50
2   Allan                      24
3   unknowndomain              23
4   Monomeeth                  21
5   bmike                      18
```

A big thank you to all 33 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Does upgrading macOS causes one to lose data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335153/does-upgrading-macos-causes-one-to-lose-data)

   - Posted by: Emerald OUK
   - Votes: **9**
2. [How can I obfuscate a small section of a image on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335179/how-can-i-obfuscate-a-small-section-of-a-image-on-macos)

   - Posted by: user674669
   - Votes: **7**

   [I want my Mac running Sierra, to stop hiding dock when I enter “Command+Option+D”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333635/i-want-my-mac-running-sierra-to-stop-hiding-dock-when-i-enter-commandoptiond)

   - Posted by: Jeanette S
   - Votes: **7**
3. [Fishy moves at night](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334826/fishy-moves-at-night)

   - Posted by: tonychow0929
   - Votes: **6**

   [“bash -D” command doesn't seem to do anything useful](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334174/bash-d-command-doesnt-seem-to-do-anything-useful)

   - Posted by: StevieD
   - Votes: **6**

   [Which folders should be copied when performing a manual backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333134/which-folders-should-be-copied-when-performing-a-manual-backup)

   - Posted by: Michaël Polla
   - Votes: **6**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [Does upgrading macOS causes one to lose data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335153/does-upgrading-macos-causes-one-to-lose-data/335154#335154)

   - Posted by: Nimesh Neema
   - Votes: **24**
2. [I want my Mac running Sierra, to stop hiding dock when I enter “Command+Option+D”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333635/i-want-my-mac-running-sierra-to-stop-hiding-dock-when-i-enter-commandoptiond/333639#333639)

   - Posted by: unknowndomain
   - Votes: **19**
3. [Is it normal to have same user logged in twice but from another TTY?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334487/is-it-normal-to-have-same-user-logged-in-twice-but-from-another-tty/334490#334490)

   - Posted by: Kysh
   - Votes: **11**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Is it normal to have same user logged in twice but from another TTY?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334487/is-it-normal-to-have-same-user-logged-in-twice-but-from-another-tty)

   - Posted by: jennifer ruurs
   - Views: **2,053**
2. [Does upgrading macOS causes one to lose data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335153/does-upgrading-macos-causes-one-to-lose-data)

   - Posted by: Emerald OUK
   - Views: **1,145**
3. [I want my Mac running Sierra, to stop hiding dock when I enter “Command+Option+D”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333635/i-want-my-mac-running-sierra-to-stop-hiding-dock-when-i-enter-commandoptiond)

   - Posted by: Jeanette S
   - Views: **859**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [Mark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2313/mark)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan) / [Mark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2313/mark)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Emerald OUK](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/300502/emerald-ouk)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [jennifer ruurs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/299235/jennifer-ruurs)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In August our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 418 flags with an average handling time of 48 minutes. In summary, we also:

- deleted 298 comments
- deleted 224 posts
- closed 110 posts
- edited 168 posts
- created 75 posts
- created 409 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

Comment: What is the query you use for these especially the close vote one? or better the Reopen one

Comment: @Mark Actually, I don’t run a query, opting to use the advanced stats on the review queues instead. I import these into Excel and a range of formulas calculate a *score* based on all actions a user takes.

For example, let’s say two users (A and B) have reviewed Close Votes during the month. If they both reviewed 10 questions, but user B also added a comment on six of those questions and edited two others, then User B gets an overall higher score than User A. I take this approach as the idea is to recognise how *active* users are and *hopefully* encourage others to become more active.

Comment: On reflection, I have changed the "Reviews" label to "Score" on some of the metrics as that more accurately conveys what the value being displayed is. I’ve also changed the metric heading to better convey what we’re talking about (e.g.  "Most Close Votes Reviewed" has been changed to "Most Active Close Vote Reviewers"). Thanks for asking me about this, as I probably wouldn’t have thought to make these changes otherwise! :)

Comment: Edited "Jbis"→"JBis" :)